# Null value when Pass values [FromBody] to post method by Postman plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I use api controller in ASP.net web API and i need to pass value to post method by [FromBody] type..

```
 [HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage Post( [FromBody]string name)
 {
     ....
 }
```

i use **Postman** plugin but when send to post method value of **name** always is **null**.. follow this image:
[image]

and in Post methods :
[image]

why this happend?!

Comment: Change [FromBody] attribute on controller action to [FromForm]

Comment: Changing to FromForm let the program run, but it didn't transmit the data.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can't bind a single primitive string using json and FromBody, json will transmit an object and the controller will expect an complex object (model) in turn. If you want to only send a single string then use url encoding.

On your header set

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

The body of the POST request message body should be `=saeed` (based on your test value) and nothing else. For unknown/variable strings you have to URL encode the value so that way you do not accidentally escape with an input character.

---

### Alternate 1

Create a model and use that instead.

Message body value: `{"name":"saeee"}`

c#

```
public class CustomModel {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Controller Method

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]CustomModel model)
```

### Alternate 2

Pass primitive strings to your post using the URI instead of the message body.

Comment: Thanks ;) Alternate 1 worked

Comment: I was using an alternative to Postman called Insomnia, here I had chosen "Form URL Encoded", which gave the content type as specified, but I gave the parameter the name of the c# parameter which did not work, instead I only had to insert the value and no name, that way the request became =value not param=value

Answer (score 76):

Post the string with raw json, and do not forget the double quotation marks.

[image]

Comment: Oh man....This is the single most efficient answer i've found till date

Comment: This is the best answer to this question. It worked.