# How to send a post request with parameter?

Tags: postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a WebAPI with Visual Studio 2017 using its .Net Core template.  I am able to test my Get() code with Postman and everything works correctly.  Now, I would like to send a Post request so it calls the following code.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] string value)
{
  Console.WriteLine("value" + value);
}
```

However, I get the following error when call

**https://localhost:44364/api/carbon?value=100**

```
{
    "": [
        "A non-empty request body is required."
    ]
}
```

I am sure the problem lies with they way my Postman is setup but it looks correct.

[image]

Any suggestions?  Thank you!

**Updated per suggestion**

I added key/value to the body and received "The input was not valid."

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use Query string.You need to post the string with raw json, and do not forget the double quotation marks.Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703846/null-value-when-pass-values-frombody-to-post-method-by-postman-plugin) to get more details on post methods by Postman.
[image]

Comment: That worked!  Thank you.  How do you do the same thing but with two parameters in the function like this "Put(int id, [FromBody] string value) { }" ?

Comment: You could see [HttpPut("{id}")] attribute routing above the action, then you just need to select `PUT` and pass the id from url like  `https://localhost:44363/api/values/1`

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're receiving is very descriptive of the problem - you haven't provided a body in your request.

Click "Body" in Postman (next to "Headers") then select the type of body you want to send, for example `x-www-form-urlencoded` and then add a key/value pair beneath, e.g. `test` and `hello world`.

Hit "Send".